# Вставка информации в БД с помощью JS

Tags: include, база-данных, javascript

Всем доброго времени суток!

Подскажите кусок кода для вставки информации в БД с помощью JS.

Comment: Что?? "ин-ции" — что это за слово? Вы экономите электронные чернила? С помощью JS в БД ничего нельзя вставить, если только у вас код не на  Node.JS

Comment: информации. Нет, я даю повод людям вставить свои умные высказывания!

Comment: А если внутрь JS кода вставить php-файл с кодом для вставки?

Comment: >А если внутрь JS кода вставить php-файл с кодом для вставки?

вы сатану вызовите

Comment: Пасиб, посмеялся :)

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript в основном (ну кроме вот этого например [смотреть тут](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js\)) - язык, используемый на клиенте. Поэтому никакой "кусок ин-ции" в БД с его помощью вы не вставите. Если бы с клиента можно было вот так запросто оперировать базой данных, что находится где-то на сервере, то это было бы...эммм...скажем так, небезопасно. А вот это ваше

> А если внутрь JS кода вставить php-файл с кодом для вставки?

мягко говоря, чепуха. Но тем не менее для взаимодействия клиента с сервером вы, например, можете использовать [ajax-запрос](http://javascript.ru/ajax/intro)

Answer (score 1):

1. создаем на джаваскрипт функцию-запрос к серверному скрипту, в запросе передаем информацию для вставки
2. создаем на пхп, ноде.жс, и т.д. скрипт, который принимает информацию запроса и отправляет его в БД

клиент:

```
    $.ajax({type: "GET", url: "worker.php", data:"d=12345678", dataType:"text", timeout:30000, async:false,

        error: function(xhr) { 
        console.log(xhr.status+' '+xhr.statusText); // поймали ошибку
        },
       success: function(html) {
        console.log(html); // результат выполнения запроса
        }
    });
```

сервер:

```
$data=$_GET("d");
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");
$query="INSERT INTO table (table_field) VALUES ($data)"; // записали 12345678 в какую-то таблицу
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Query failed : " . mysql_error()); 
mysql_close($link);
$echo($result);  // вернем результат отправки в базу, для контроля
```

пример весьма упрощен, на понимание процесса

Comment: `async:false` зачем?

Comment: для форсу бандитского :) обычно стараюсь за типом запроса явно следить, чтобы потом не искать черную кошку в темной комнате когда ее там нет